# Access the element inside of dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a Python dict, I am trying to access the element inside it,

```
data = [{
    u 'InstanceId': 'i-0729fd87c30489d12', u 'InstanceState': {
        u 'Code': 16, u 'Name': 'running'
    }, u 'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-2a', u 'SystemStatus': {
        u 'Status': 'ok', u 'Details': [{
            u 'Status': 'passed', u 'Name': 'reachability'
        }]
    }, u 'InstanceStatus': {
        u 'Status': 'ok', u 'Details': [{
            u 'Status': 'passed', u 'Name': 'reachability'
        }]
    }
}]
```

Python version : 2.7

I want to access the element `Name` and it should be give me output `running`

Command I am using, `data["InstanceState"]["Name"]`

But it is giving the error,

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: data is not a `dict`, it is a `list`, as the Exception thrown shows you (listening to the exceptions will let you catch on to what is happening quite quickly most of the time). If you remove the outer brackets, or access the dict item in the list of dictionaries (length 1), it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary you think you're accessing is actually located in a list. More specifically, it's the first item in the list `data` (yes, data is a list).

Do `data[0]["InstanceState"]["Name"]`

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally put your dictionary inside a list with one element.

```python
data = {
    u 'InstanceId': 'i-0729fd87c30489d12', u 'InstanceState': {
        u 'Code': 16, u 'Name': 'running'
    }, u 'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-2a', u 'SystemStatus': {
        u 'Status': 'ok', u 'Details': [{
            u 'Status': 'passed', u 'Name': 'reachability'
        }]
    }, u 'InstanceStatus': {
        u 'Status': 'ok', u 'Details': [{
            u 'Status': 'passed', u 'Name': 'reachability'
        }]
    }
}
```

Your code will now work. Just remove the outer square brackets.
You have made the same mistake with the `data["InstanceStatus"]["Details"]` dictionary.

Comment: You have also made the mistake with the `data["InstanceStatus"]["Details"]` dictionary: you put it inside a list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fair Point; Will do that now.